# Image from path wont load

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I got this listener:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showDialog();
        ImageButton currentButton = (ImageButton)v;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        currentButton.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }
```

Image is successfully taken in `showDialog()` but after this it wont set to `imageButton`. It goes white. The path generated is:
`file:/storage........../filename.jpg` amd its saved in `mCurrentPhotoPath`
I tried setting image from `drawable` after shot is made just to try it and it works. For some reason i cant set the image to the `ImageButton`.Do i have to resize it(photo is made full sized)? 
Following [THIS](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) tutorial i did this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog((ImageButton)v);
    setPic((ImageButton)v);
}

private void setPic(ImageButton mImageView) {
    if (shotFired){
        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,bmOptions);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        mImageView.setTag(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        shotFired=false;

    }
```

Seems if i calll `setPic()` without making a new shot and just call the old one ive made it works. Must be something in timing...I need to get this thing working.

Comment: are you launching camera from showDialog??

Comment: "The path generated is: file:/storage........../filename.jpg" -- that is not a path. That is not a valid `Uri` either, so I do not know what that is. But, `decodeFile()` is not going to recognize it.

Comment: I did all this following the tutorial i just posted.

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh yes i am

Comment: any ideas? still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using camera for taking the picture to set it to ImageView, then you need to set the image in onActivityResult() after the image is captured using camera.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //set the image to imageView


    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //image was not taken 
        //show some error message

    }

}
```

Comment: My bad. I was calling the `setPic()` after calling popup and not in `onActivityResult()`. Now its working

Answer (score 1):

i believe you problem is because of outOfMEmory problem that normaly happens  when loading a bitmap into the memory.

the best practice to load bitmaps in android is to find the bitmap dimensions before you load it. then loading a suitable size of the bitmap depend on your device memory size and screen size.

i highly recommend you to read this great tutorial in develope.android website. this will help you to get a complete sens about how bitmaps works and whats the best practice to load them also source code is included. please go through all these tutorials.

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

i suggest you to read these links but if you nor intersted you can use libraries like Glide or Piccasso for loading your bitmap. they will help you to load without an OutOfMemoty Error.

Comment: i did it and i still have the same plroblem

Comment: This was not the solution in my case but made it possible. Upvoted